# Bash pattern matching inside [[ test block

Tags: regex, bash, shell, pattern-matching

I am making a script that can do the same task on several machines, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ hostname = login.machine1 ]]; then
    #do things how they are done on machine1
    ...
elif [[ hostname = login.machine2 ]]; then
    #etc.
fi
```

Problem: some machines have several login nodes, like `login1.machine2`, `login2.machine2`, etc.  I have tried shell pattern matching and regex but none of them work:

```
if [[ hostname = login?.machine2 ]]
if [[ hostname == login?.machine2 ]]
if [[ hostname =~ login[0-9].machine2 ]]
if [[ hostname =~ login[0-9]\.machine2 ]]
```

and at least a dozen similar patterns, with or without quotes, etc.  What is the correct way to make a test that will return true if hostname = login1.machine2 OR login2.machine2, etc.?  Bonus points for something that works with `[` instead of `[[`.

Comment: I suggest to use variable `$HOSTNAME` or output of command hostname: `$(hostname)`.

Comment: I don't know what kind of shell you're using. But in bash `if [[ $(hostname) = login?.machine2 ]]` this will check if hostname is equal to the string "login?.machine2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `hostname` needs to be wrapped:

```
if [[ $(hostname) = login?.machine2 ]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a $ before hostname to use the variable.

```
if [[ $hostname =~ login[0-9]\.machine2 ]]; then
   echo "ok"
fi
```

And for the single `[` (sh), the regexp operator `=~` was added on bash, so it should not be possible to do it natively with sh.

Comment: That is supposed to be the command `hostname`, not a variable.  Once I replaced it with `$(hostname)` my first try with plain shell pattern matching worked, no regex needed.  Success!

Answer (score 0):

Is `[[ hostname =~ ... ]]` supposed to call the command `hostname` or do you have a variable called `hostname`? Either use `$HOSTNAME` or the command substitution `$(hostname)`

If concerned about portability AWK can be used, with old school command substitutions:

```
if printf "%s\n" "`hostname`" | awk '!/login[[:digit:]]\.machine2/{exit 1}'; then
  printf "Matches...\n"
else
  printf "Doesn't match\n"
fi
```

If not I would highly recommend [the answer by naab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37686185/887539)